# multiple VueJS apps with one prepage - navigate to each app without redirect

Tags: vue.js

we are developing a bigger project based on different VueJS applications. Each VueJS application has its own router and store.

The applications are accessed e. a. like this:

`https://baseurl.com/app1/#/
https://baseurl.com/app2/#/
https://baseurl.com/app3/#/`

Now we would like to add a pre page to navigate to all these apps. The pre page will be located at `https://baseurl.com/`

For a better user experience we do not want to use a simple redirect to each application. The goal would be that the user doesn't notice, that he is navigating to another vue application. It should feel like one big application with the baseurl as the entry point.

Is there a good solution for such a case?

What we already thought about:

1. For the pre page we would use VanillaJS/JQuery to dynamically load each application into the curernt DOM. Question: Is the router instance of each app available?
2. For the pre page we would use another VueJS app and use the router for external routes (here again would be a redirect visible)

Would be happy about some advices how to make many small VueJS applications to "a big one".

Its not an option to develop all sub applications into one big VueJS projects since all sub apps should be very flexibel and do not be able to "disturb" the other apps.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I mean it would be stupid to not make it into a big one considering the options you have with a component based system,lazy loading routes , store modules etc. you could make it into one without letting them disturb each other, i doubt that you can do that what you want with different projects considering it has to run smooth

Comment: @Badgy thanks for your comment. The point is that there are already 6 applications created by different developers. Each developer will care only about his own application and his own build process. We would like to find a way that all this apps are handled like modules for the pre page. If one "module" is crashing cause of a bug... the other apps should still work fine - cause they are independent

Comment: I am not really sure how to do this without refreshing the page and importing the new bundle, but you could have some global javascript that switches different html's. If you don't mind refreshing the page, you can take a look at this example on how to handle Vue and multiple "mini spa's". [Github link](https://github.com/danijelh/aspnetcore-vue-typescript-template)

Comment: Let's go crazy and use an iframe. Fade it in smoothly when it's loaded.

Comment: Why not just make a simple html landing page with `<a href>` links to the apps? If they share the same style, the user will likely not notice that there are different apps.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but just leaving this here.
If you wanna switch apps without reloading maybe try server side rendering? [Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/) will come handy it has converts your apps into static HTML files.